# C# class that handle MySQL db connection

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I've built a class that handles all my connections to a MySql database.

These are the function I use to create the connection(not really sure about the two dispose functions) :

```
 public class dbConnection : IDisposable
{
    public MySqlConnection conn;
    public MySqlTransaction transaction;

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public dbConnection()
    {
        string host = "1.1.1.1"; 
        string usernameMySql = "admin";
        string pswMySql = "password";
        string nomeDb = "db1";

        string connStr = "Database=" + nomeDb + ";" +
                "Data Source=" + host + ";" +
                "User Id=" + usernameMySql + ";Password=" + pswMySql + "";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    }

    public void openConnection()
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Open();
        transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void closeConnection()
    {
        transaction.Commit();
        conn.Close();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(Boolean disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

These are the functions I use to read/write data:

```
public void ExecuteSQL(string sSql)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sSql, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public MySqlDataReader readerSQL(string sSql)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sSql, conn);
        MySqlDataReader readerSql = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        return readerSql;
    }

    protected int ExecuteSQLReturnId(string sSql)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sSql, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.LastInsertedId);
    }
```

In others part of my project i then use

```
db = new dbConnection();
db.openConnection();
```

to create a new connection.

This code works but I'm not really sure it's the right way to handle things, Are there any improvements that can be made ?

Comment: To review this...I'd simply drop it. It adds almost nothing to existing classes (and it messes up with disposing, pretty bad!). If you really need something to _short_ your code you may just write two/three helper methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's the point of `dbConnection`? As it stands now it is a barely-there wrapper around `MySqlConnection` with a built-in connection string(!) and some odd behavior when you call `openConnection()`. You claim this works, are you sure -- because why wouldn't `conn.Close();` throw an exception if there isn't an open connection?

---

Why do you always open a transaction? Why is your connection string hard-coded?

---

This code:

- doesn't follow [capitalization standards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229043.aspx),
- doesn't use [a using statement](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using) to encapsulate classes that implement `IDisposable` (which should also be used when dealing with `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader` etc.),
- has bad variable names like `readerSql`, `usernameMySql`,...

Comment: How should I handle the connection string ? Just pass it in a initialize function ?

Comment: @SilentRage47 Traditionally it is in the Web.config or App.config, [which you then can read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net).